# Partial differential operator of a measure

Tags: measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, definition

A paper by de Philippis and Rindler, titled *On the Structure of $\mathscr{A}$-Free Measures and Applications*, opens as follows:

Let $\mu$ be a Radon measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with values in $\mathbb{R}^m$ that is $\mathscr{A}$-free for a $k$th order linear constant-coefficient PDE operator $\mathscr{A}$, i.e.
$$
\mathscr{A}\mu = \sum_{|\alpha| \leq k}A_\alpha \partial^\alpha \mu.
$$
Here $A_\alpha$ is an $n \times m$ (real-valued) matrix and $\alpha = (\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_d)$ is a multi-index.

Sadly, I cannot move past this first sentence. I know basic measure theory and PDE theory, and if anyone is able to  help answer my question, it would be much appreciated.

Basically, I don't even know what on earth the partial derivative of a measure is. I hear my professor mention that it is made sense of through the theory of distributions. I have looked at some resources on distributions,  but have not yet seen any mention of PDE operators in them (perhaps I have not looked long enough, though). So my question is, what does the operator $\mathscr{A}$ even mean? An additional question after this would be, what does it mean for a measure $\mu$ to be $\mathscr{A}$-free, although clearly this comes after the former question.

If anyone could help answer, or perhaps refer me to a resource, that would be wonderful.

Comment: Yeah, you are going to have to learn distribution theory to make sense of this.  It's a standard thing to define a partial derivative of a distribution (via integration by parts), and then this partial differential operator is just a linear combination of those partial derivatives.  So you may not see partial differential operators described explicitly, because all you really need to understand is partial derivatives.

Comment: The definition of $\mathscr{A}$-free appears in section 2.1 of the paper ([arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.06543)).  It just means $\mathscr{A} \mu = 0$ in the sense of distributions.  It's actually also stated in the very sentence you quoted ("i.e.").